# Is there a method to simply transpose a table in SQL. This table contains Numeric and Varchar values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, unpivot

I would like to know how to transpose very simply a table in SQL. There is no sum or calculations to do.

This table contains Numeric and Varchar values.

Meaning, I have a table of 2 rows x 195 columns. I would like to have the same table with 195 rows x 2 columns (maybe 3 columns)

| time_index | legal_entity_code | cohort | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAA | 50 | ... | ... |
| 1 | BBB | 55 | ... | ... |

TO

| Element | time_index_0 | time_index_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| legal_entity_code | AAA | BBB |
| cohort | 50 | 55 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... |

I have created this piece of code for testing

```
SELECT  time_index, ValueT, FieldName
FROM   (select legal_entity_code, cohort, time_index from ifrs17.output_bba where id in (1349392,1349034)) as T
UNPIVOT
(
    ValueT
    FOR FieldName in ([legal_entity_code],[cohort])
) as P
```

but I receive this error message :

> The type of column "cohort" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; what about the error don't you understand and we can try to elaborate.

Comment: Your question and your code are not consistent.  It is a bit hard to follow.

Comment: Indeed sorry guys for the inconsitency. Name1 would be 'legal entity code', Value1 would be 'cohort'. etc ... the table contains normaly 195 columns. In the piece of code I presented only 3 of them (for simplicity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gordon's approach is correct and certainly more performant.  +1

However, if you want to dynamically unpivot 195 columns without having to list them all, consider the following:

Note: if not 2016+ ... there is a similar XML approach.

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=928d34952bbe513937fd3624d334d9f1)**

```
Select Element = [Key]
      ,Time_Index_0 = max(case when time_index=0 then value end)
      ,Time_Index_1 = max(case when time_index=1 then value end)
 From  (
        Select [time_index]
              ,B.*
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                      Select [Key]
                            ,Value
                       From OpenJson( (Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper ) ) 
                       Where [Key] not in ('time_index')
                     ) B
        ) A
 Group By [Key]
```

**Returns**

```
Element             Time_Index_0    Time_Index_1
cohort              50              55
legal_entity_code   AAA             BBB
```

Comment: Crazy !! Thanks a lot John and the others who replied! It helps me very much !!!

Comment: @Nassim Always happy to help

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `apply` for this.  I don't fully follow the specified results because the query and the sample data are inconsistent in their naming.

I'm pretty sure you want:

```
select o.time_index, v.*
from ifrs17.output_bba o cross apply
     (values ('Name1', o.name1),
             ('Value1', convert(varchar(max), o.value1)),
             ('Name2', o.name2)
     ) v(name, value)            
where o.id in (1349392,1349034);
```

Comment: Oh sorry for the inconsistency. Name1 would be 'legal entity code', Value1 would be 'cohort'. etc ... the table contains normaly 195 columns. In the piece of code I presented only 3 of them (for simplicity)